# Read data from XML file (in Java) using Reflection

Tags: java, xml, reflection

Given a simple XML file , like :

```
<Game>
    <Round>
        <roundNumber>1</roundNumber>
        <Door>
            <doorName>abd11</doorName>
            <Value>
                <xVal1>0</xVal1>
                <xVal2>25</xVal2>
                <pVal>0.31</pVal>
            </Value>
            <Value>
                <xVal1>25</xVal1>
                <xVal2>50</xVal2>
                <pVal>0.04</pVal>
            </Value>
            <Value>
                <xVal1>50</xVal1>
                <xVal2>75</xVal2>
                <pVal>0.19</pVal>
            </Value>
            <Value>
                <xVal1>75</xVal1>
                <xVal2>100</xVal2>
                <pVal>0.46</pVal>
            </Value>
        </Door>
        <Door>
            <doorName>vvv1133</doorName>
            <Value>
                <xVal1>60</xVal1>
                <xVal2>62</xVal2>
                <pVal>1.0</pVal>
            </Value>
        </Door>
    </Round>
    <Round>
        <roundNumber>2</roundNumber>
        <Door>
            <doorName>eee</doorName>
            <Value>
                <xVal1>0</xVal1>
                <xVal2>-25</xVal2>
                <pVal>0.31</pVal>
            </Value>
            <Value>
                <xVal1>-25</xVal1>
                <xVal2>-50</xVal2>
                <pVal>0.04</pVal>
            </Value>
            <Value>
                <xVal1>-50</xVal1>
                <xVal2>-75</xVal2>
                <pVal>0.19</pVal>
            </Value>
            <Value>
                <xVal1>-75</xVal1>
                <xVal2>-100</xVal2>
                <pVal>0.46</pVal>
            </Value>
        </Door>
        <Door>
            <doorName>cc</doorName>
            <Value>
                <xVal1>-60</xVal1>
                <xVal2>-62</xVal2>
                <pVal>0.3</pVal>
            </Value>
            <Value>
                <xVal1>-70</xVal1>
                <xVal2>-78</xVal2>
                <pVal>0.7</pVal>
            </Value>
        </Door>
    </Round>
</Game>
```

I want to read data from that file .

I can do it in the old fashioned way of reading the tags , and create the objects accordingly ,

but I want to do it using Reflection mechanism .

Can someone please explain or direct me to a tutorial that can explain how to do that ?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

I did the following :

```
import java.io.File;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.*;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; 

public class ReadAndPrintXMLFile {


    public static void main (String argv []){
    try {

            DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.parse (new File("input.xml"));


            // ROOT 

            // normalize text representation
            doc.getDocumentElement ().normalize ();
            System.out.println ("Root element of the doc is " + 
                 doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());


            // Number of nodes/rounds 


            NodeList listOfItems = doc.getElementsByTagName("Round");
            int totalElements = listOfItems.getLength();
            System.out.println("Total number of nodes : " + totalElements );
...
...
}
```

This is a partial code , I ran the code and tested it , and at the moment , using SAX , I 
can read from the XML file above .

Now , what I want to do is to manipulate the data using Reflection . From my understanding Reflection works only with EXISTING objects . Hence , is it enough to store the data (I.E. the rounds)  in the variable `listOfItems` and now use Reflection on that ?

thanks again !

Comment: I am not sure where exactly you want to use reflection in the process of processing XML file.  Are you planning to use reflection while creation objects for each tag in the XML?

Comment: @Seshagiri: Yes, I want to read the information from the XML and then manipulate it in runtime .

Comment: Reflection is for messing around with Java classes, not XML files. So explain what you mean by using reflection a bit more... EDIT: Is there anything stopping you from manipulating them on the run-time with normal objects and Java XML API??

Comment: @Thihara: Yes , I must use reflection since it's homework , otherwise I wouldn't be asking you that question ,since I know how to read XML in the usual way . thanks .

Comment: Reflection only deals with java classes, for XML parsing we have to depend on parsers depending on what you want to do.  If you want to use reflection for creating objects after parsing XML, some where we should map each element with their corresponding Fully Qualified Class Name  and for which property that particular element will be mapped.

Comment: yeah but it easier if he creates an object model and read XML data into them. Then use reflection to manipulate them in whatever way he need just to show the teacher he can ;-) EDIT: I think thats what you mean anyway Seshagiri, sorry didn't read your comment properly..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well in that case I guess you can read the XML files into Java using Java XML api as paulsm4 suggested and use reflection to get them and manupulate them.

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/

This is dead so try this one. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html

This is not the best tutorial but it should be enough for what you need. And may I suggest that this is a very poor use of reflection API, and therefore I want to throw an egg at whoever gave you the homework assignment :-D

EDIT: Yes if you wish you can use reflection on that.. Or you can create an object model(Classes for Door, Round and Game) and populate them with values in the XML file and then use reflection on it to whatever that need to be done. It upto you to decide how best you want to do that!

Comment: Ha ha I guess I missed the point, I thought you were gonna do something with the data using reflection. Yes in the scenario you are telling about go reflect on the listOfItems...

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you read it the "old fashioned way" of using one of the Java XML APIs?????

Google for "Java XML", "SAX", "DOM", "DocumentBuilder", "org.w3c.dom", etc and you'll find lots of good documentation and tutorials.  For example:

- http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/javax.xml.parsers/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java.html
- http://java.sun.com/xml/tutorial_intro.html
- http://java.sun.com/xml/docs.html
- http://www.thedeveloperspoint.com/?p=220

Comment: If I could , I would have, however I must use reflection (homework) while reading the XML .

Answer (score 2):

You have something like:

```
GameRound >>
  int roundNumber
  Door door >>
    String doorName
    Value value >>
      int xVal1
      int xVal2
      float pVal
```

And you wish to parse your xml and populate your objects? Is this correct?

If yes, I don't see the point! Even if you don't want to use any api, write your own and populate the values via setters!

@Thihara +1 for the egg xD

Comment: One question, WHY will you use reflection after populating the object?

You can on the other hand use reflection to find the setters corresponding to the names of the nodes you parse! I cannot think of anything better :[